# Is a basic hypergeometric function ${}_2\phi_1(a, b; c; q, z)$ a meromorphic function in $z$?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions, q-analogs

Here a basic hypergeometric function is the analytic continuation of the basic hypergeometric series (or called the $q$-hypergeometric series)

$$
{}_2\phi_1(a, b; c; q, z) = \sum^{\infty}_{n = 0} \frac{(a; q)_k (b; q)_k}{(c; q)_k (q; q)_k} z^k.
$$

A common way to construct the analytic continuation is by [Watson's contour integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_hypergeometric_series#Watson.27s_contour_integral)

$$
{}_2\phi_1(a, b; c; q, z) = \frac{(a; q)_{\infty} (b; q)_{\infty}}{(c; q)_{\infty} (q; q)_{\infty}} \left( \frac{-1}{2\pi i} \right) \int^{i\infty}_{-i\infty} \frac{(cq^s; q)_{\infty} (q^{1 + s}; q)_{\infty}}{(aq^s; q)_{\infty} (bq^s; q)_{\infty}} \frac{\pi (-z)^s}{\sin(\pi s)} ds,
$$

which is a $q$-analogue of [Barnes's contour integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_integral) of the hypergeometric series.

Formally, Watson's integral has a branch cut along the positive real axis. In the book *Basic hypergeometric series* by Gasper and Rahman, the basic hypergeometric functions are defined on the domain $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}_+$.

This domain seems to be natural, since the hypergeometric series, which is the $q \rightarrow 1$ limit of the basic hypergeometric series, generally has a branch cut from $1$ to $\infty$ and is not meromorphic.

However, basic hypergeometric series has functional identities like *Heine's first transformation* ([DLMF 17.6.6](http://dlmf.nist.gov/17.6))

$$
{}_2\phi_1(a, b; c; q, z) = \frac{(b; q)_{\infty} (az; q)_{\infty}}{(c; q)_{\infty} (z; q)_{\infty}} {}_2\phi_1(\frac{c}{b}, z; az; q, b)
$$

if $\lvert b \rvert < 1$. Then the analytic continuation of ${}_2\phi_1(a, b; c; q, z)$ can be obtained by the right-hand side of the identity above, which is a meromorphic function in $z$.

I guess all well-defined basic hypergeometric functions are meromorphic, with poles $1, q^{-1}, q^{-2}, \dots$.

**Question:**

(1) Is there a good reference book for this property?

(2) Is there a simple way to see that Watson's contour integral defines a meromorphic function, to the contrast that Barnes's contour integral defines a function with non-trivial branch cut?

Comment: in general, the hypergeometric "function" is multivalued. You have to go to the universal cover to think of it as a function. Near $z=1$ , the function looks like $(z-1)^{\alpha}$ which is clearly multivalued.

Comment: I know that the usual hypergeometric functions are multivalued, but it seems that the **basic** hypergeometric functions, in spite of being more complicated, are meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$. Hence I posed the question.

Comment: I would say t is even meromorphic at infinity (if it is single valued); hence it would be a rational function, for special choice of parameters.

Comment: In the example that I give for $\lvert b \rvert < 1$, you can see that the meromorphic function has infinitely many poles at $1, q^{-1}, q^{-2}, \dots$. So it should not be a rational function generally.

Comment: every hypergeometric function is regular except at 0,1, infinity, so this is something else

Comment: This question is about **Basic** hypergeometric functions, a $q$-analogue of the usual hypergeometric functions.

Comment: From Heine transformation that you give, seems like there must be also poles at $a^{-1},a^{-1}q^{-1},a^{-1}q^{-2},...$; similarly, Heine's second transformation suggests $b^{-1}q^{-n}$

Comment: This starts to look dangerous - there are so many transformations, maybe they will produce so many poles that after all their set will not be discrete anymore...